# Looping html5 video in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, video

According to this demo, it SHOULD be possible to loop video in Chrome

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_loop

but I can't seem to get it working when I simply apply

```
loop="loop"
```

to my video tag.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What's your code? The linked demo works fine here (Chrome 18 Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: According to W3Schools too, they know what they are talking about.

Comment: Yes no doubt. I'll post a demo later. But it definitely plays(loops) fine in Safari, and the webm version plays and loops in Firefox. Just Chrome where I have the issue. Could be the specific build of Chrome I am using as well. More to follow...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that this post is rather old or might be resolved. In case you are just wondering let me point to a different threat.

I think the reason why you can't loop the video in Chrome is that for chrome the video only loops when served up by a server that understands partial content requests.

More on that here: [HTML5 video will not loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop)

I thought that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 the 'loop' attribute is a Boolean so you should write:

```
loop='true'
```