# HTML5 video won't play in Chrome only

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, mediaelement.js

### some background

I've tested my video in FF and Safari (including iDevices) and it plays properly, but it will not play in the Chrome browser. As you can see in the code below, I've created mp4, m4v, webM, and ogv files, and I've tested all of them on my computer for any playback issues.

### the symptoms/issue

In Chrome, the video seems to load, and there are **no errors in the console log**. When the play button is pressed, it loads a portion of the file, but then does not play it. Yet, interestingly, if I arbitrarily click on a later time in the time-bar, say about halfway through, it will play about 5 seconds of the video even with the subtitles, but **no** audio.

### my research

I've read up on any issues that might be causing this, but I haven't found any ideas that work. To note, I've written the following in my .htaccess file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a
AddType audio/webm                     webm

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm

# Assorted types
AddType image/x-icon                        ico
AddType image/webp                          webp
AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component                    htc
AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf
AddType text/plain                          srt
```

Also, I am using the mediaelement.js library.

### the code

Here's the HTML:

```
<video width="100%" height="400" poster="assets/img/myVideo.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
      <!-- M4V for Apple -->
      <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.m4v" />
      <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
      <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.mp4" />
      <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
      <source type="video/webm" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.webm" />
      <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
      <source type="video/ogg" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.ogv" />
      <!-- Subtitles -->
      <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/vid/subtitles.srt" srclang="en" />
      <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/vid/subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" />
      <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
      <object width="100%" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
          <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.mp4" />
          <!-- Image as a last resort -->
          <img src="assets/img/myVideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
      </object>
</video>
```

Here's the simple js:

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
    features: ['playpause','progress','current','tracks','volume'],
    startLanguage: 'en'
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for any and all help in this matter!

Comment: Firefox supports MP4/H264 nowadays btw http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/26.0/releasenotes/

Comment: And what is .m4v? Why can't you get away with a MP4 for all devices?

Comment: @hendry: it looks as though it is supported only on Linux platforms, though, and I need to make it as widely accessible as possible. Regarding the .m4v file. It's for Apples devices.

With some help, I think I've narrowed it down to a codec issue and possible ordering of the source types w/in the video element. I'll be tinkering away today, and post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With some help from another person, we figured out it was an issue of ordering the  source files within the HTML file. I learned that browsers accept the first usable format, and their seems to be an issue with the .m4v file, so I started with the .mp4, then .webm. Here's the order that works in Safari (even on my iPhone 5), Firefox, **and Chrome**:

```
<video width="100%" height="400" poster="assets/img/myVideo.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
      <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
      <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.mp4" />
      <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
      <source type="video/webm" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.webm" />
       <!-- M4V for Apple -->
      <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.m4v" />
      <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
      <source type="video/ogg" src="assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.ogv" />
      <!-- Subtitles -->
      <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/vid/subtitles.srt" srclang="en" />
      <track kind="subtitles" src="assets/vid/subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" />
      <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
      <object width="100%" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
          <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
          <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=assets/vid/PhysicsEtoys.mp4" />
          <!-- Image as a last resort -->
          <img src="assets/img/myVideo.jpg" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
      </object>
  </video>
```

Now, I'll have to re-check the encoding on the m4v file (perhaps an issue of Baseline vs Main, High, etc.).

Comment: So what exactly is the resolution here?

Comment: @ItGrunt i believe he just changed the order of his <source>'s to have the .mp4 source first.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted plays-inline>
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/158148793.hd.mp4?s=8e8741dbee251d5c35a759718d4b0976fbf38b6f&profile_id=119&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

Thanks

Comment: `plays-inline` pretty much fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: the attribute is called `playsinline` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. Changing muted to **[muted]="true"** did fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, no videos would play in Chrome. Tried installing beta 64bit, going back to Chrome 32bit release.

The only thing that worked for me was **updating my video drivers**.

I have the NVIDIA GTS 240. Downloaded, installed the drivers and restarted and Chrome 38.0.2125.77 beta-m (64-bit) starting playing HTML5 videos again on youtube, vimeo and others. Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: the youtube video is fine. But the another mp4 stream resources seems failed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by setting the MIME type of your .m4v to "video/m4v" or "video/x-m4v" ?

Browsers might use the `canPlayType` method internally to check if a `<source>` is candidate to playback.

In Chrome, I have these results:

```
document.createElement("video").canPlayType("video/mp4"); // "maybe"
document.createElement("video").canPlayType("video/m4v"); // ""
document.createElement("video").canPlayType("video/x-m4v"); // "maybe"
```

Comment: Interesting. How do you find/check for those results, so I can check such things in the future?

Comment: Simply launch these lines in your browser's console :)

Comment: what does the maybe mean?

Comment: The canPlayType just give you the information if the browser is capable to open the video container (mp4, mov, avi are just containers, a box capable to store audio and/or video streams). So, the browser may be able to open the box, but maybe it won't be able to play the stream (for example, the browser may open an mp4 but won't be able to decode the video stream if the bitrate is too high for the device).

Comment: you can also check your setings on [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

Comment: document.createElement("video").canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"');
"probably"

Answer (score 0):

To all of you who got here and did not found the right solution,
i found out that the mp4 video needs to fit a specific format.

My Problem was that i got an 1920x1080 video which wont load under Chrome (under Firefox it worked like a charm).
After hours of searching i finaly managed to get hang of the problem, the first few streams where 1912x1088 so Chrome wont play it ( i got the exact stream size from the tool [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo%20MediaInfo)).
So to fix it i just resized it to 1920x1080 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

firstly chrome cannot read mkv files I have tried only with mp4 and webm it works fine for me.

And then check its encoding note that chrome browser only support only few encodings not all.These are supported by chrome browser.

Video Codec H.264, VP8, VP9

Audio Codec AAC, MP3, Vorbis, Opus

you can check encoding by ffmpeg using command(you need to install it)

```
ffprobe file.mp4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLfM5.png)

you can change encoding with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue -- no video would play on Google Chrome, but it worked perfectly in Safari.

I finally got it to work in two steps:

1. use VLC to convert every video to .m4v type (instead of .mp4)
2. Use this code to add in every video, making sure that it preloads and muted is set equal to true.

```
<video src="assets/VIDEOTITLE.m4v" type="video/m4v" height="400" autoplay loop class="d-block w-100" preload ="auto" muted="true"></video>
```

It seems to finally work now.