# html5 video won't loop in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, websphere-7

I'm having the same issue as described in this post:

[HTML5 video will not loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop)

So basically my videos won't loop (and cannot be seeked ) in chrome. The same markup works fine when i host my page on an apache server and even if i open it from the file system, and about a week ago it worked in a portlet over websphere appserver 7.0. All i have done on server side was adding video mime types for mp4, ogv, etc... other than that i have no idea what could have gone wrong.

Am i missing some settings on the server? Or if it is the issue with the ranged requests, how do you resolve that on websphere?

My code is like this:

```
<video preload="metadata" width="340">                      
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"  />  
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />                     
<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg"  />
</video>
```

I start the video and set the loop attribute like this:

```
var $video = ...                            
if($video && $video.canPlayType) {
$video.play();
$video.loop = 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the HTML5 loop tag?

```
<video id="yourID" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<!--source code here-->
</video>
```

EDIT: To get this to work from JavaScript do the following.

```
var video = document.createElement('video'); //To create the video element.
video.loop = true;
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634678/where-to-find-the-response-video-data   Has to do with HTML video data.