# Mediaelement.js "seeked" event listener never triggered in Chrome

Tags: html, video, mp4, mediaelement.js

In Chrome, we inconsistently see a problem with mediaelement.js loading mp4 video. If you seek by clicking the progress bar, usually it loads the video at that point with no problem, firing both the "seeking" and "seeked" event listeners in mediaelement.js. But sometimes you end up with a blank screen, no loading gif, and in the Network panel, it shows that the mp4 has been canceled. In these cases, the "seeked" event never fires.

Our server(s) sending "Partial Content" status messages that Chrome doesn't handle seems like a possible explanation as discussed here:
[HTML5 video will not loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop)

We also have several possible workarounds (replay after a certain amount of time between "seeking" and "seeked", disable seeking, force Flash) in mind if we can't figure out why this is happening.

But I'm not sure how to fix the server so that Chrome will be happier, or if there's another possible explanation for why the "seeked" event never fires.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: The issue is still there.
https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/2643