# Video.js can't jump to time while clicking on seekbar

Tags: video, video.js

I wrote a example, [Video example](http://goo.gl/bdC5nu)

Please use Chrome and view source code, you can see video1 and video2 can click on seek bar to jump to any time, but if you click video3 button, you will find seek bar can't be used to jump to specific time.

Please advise how can I enable time jump on Chrome?
And why video 3 is disabled of time jump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server needs to support partial content requests for seeking to work in Chrome. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549404/740233).