# How do I make Flask stream a static file with HTTP 206 Partial Content?

Tags: python, google-chrome, http, flask, werkzeug

I want to use a looping video on a site made powered by Flask. Apparently, Chrome will not loop the video, [unless it was streamed with an HTTP 206 code being returned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549404/568855). Flask, however, always returns this static file with an HTTP 200. How do I stream static content from my Flask project (hosted on Heroku, for the record) to make the video correctly loop in Chrome?

Comment: You probably want to [a custom buildpack with nginx](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) or some other fully featured server.  That said, Werkzeug *does* support [`Range`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/http/#werkzeug.http.parse_range_header) so it may be possible to implement it in Flask.

Comment: I ultimately did not end up implementing the answer below, I just moved these static files to a CDN.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem when serving my video files and I found the solution by digging into the source code of `Werkzeug`. I solved it by adding the flag `conditional=True` in the `send_from_directory` function as follows:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    """Endpoint to serve uploaded videos

    Use `conditional=True` in order to support range requests necessary for
    seeking videos.

    """
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename,
                               conditional=True)
```

Comment: this is a much better (and more specific) solution than my original answer.

Comment: Is there anything else you changed to make this work?  I am still getting response 200.

Answer (score 1):

Reponse objects in Flask have a "status_code" parameter you can pass.  See [this documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects) for more details, but essentially, you may want to subclass the Response object.

Also take a look at [make_response()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) - it may reveal a simpler way, depending on your application structure.

Take a look at the [streaming pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/) for more details, but it's geared towards generated content as opposed to static.