# HTML5 Audio player unseekable in chrome while works in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, laravel, html5-audio

I have built a Laravel app as follow,

Controller -> Retrieves few audio files path and sends it to view.

View -> Renders audio element with src attribute with files path obtained from controller.

I am able to play, pause. But unable to seek in chrome. Seek works fine in Firefox. I got a hint from another stackoverflow response ([HTML5 video will not loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop)) it is because that chrome get the content as partial content. How to resolve this in chrome ?

```
// Controller
public function showSamples(){
    $samples = Sample::where('artist_id', '=', Auth::user()->id));      
    return View::make('artist.samples', $samples);
}

// View [artists.sample]
@foreach($samples as $sample)
    <audio src="/uploads/samples/{{ $sample->file_path }}" controls>
    </audio>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where is your code? do you get any error in the logs? what was the SO question that you referred to in your question?........

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro edited question. There is no error. The audio player is perfectly rendered in the view. The problem is with seek bar. If I click at any place in seek bar the audio starts from beginning.

Comment: Your server needs to support byte-range requests when serving audio/video.

Comment: @idbehold Is there a way to manually enable/disable this support ? If yes, could you detail ? Like by editing some apache/http config files.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with react/s3.. Audio seek works fine in firefox but not in chrome.