# Symfony - local server - mp3 file seek

Tags: php, symfony, google-chrome

I have a very strange issue with the symfony local webserver, I'm starting it normally.

> php bin/console server:run localhost:8050
>
> [OK] Server listening on http://localhost:8050
>
> // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

I am delivering a normal mp3 file to the chrome, chrome plays it, but I cannot seek within the file. I've noticed this through the audio library that I am using. In Firefox all works well.

Chrome version: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

If I deliver the same file to the same chrome browser through Apache Webserver, all works well. 
I have the feeling it might be related to the symfony local webserver. I am using Symfony 3.3.9.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried in other browsers? there are a lot of question regarding this topic in most of them it looks like this is a bug in chrome.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. In Firefox it works(is mentioned in the question). Still, if I deliver the file through a normal webserver and not symfony's local server it works well. So, it's either a chrome issue or a symfony's local server issue. Not sure.

Comment: It seems a combination of server/browser issue. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop

Still, would love to see a workaround.